# Looking to use pseudo elements to create a triangle

Tags: css, element

I recently watched Chris Coyiers talk about pseudo elements and was looking to try and do the same.

I am looking to get the effect of an arrow pointing to the content on the right

This is the location of the li that I want to target

```
.overviews-list > li.active > ul.submenu > li.active
```

You can see from the jsfiddle the style I am going for. I think the css that needs to be changed is at the top of the css.

http://jsfiddle.net/T2HuD/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will set the positioning and create a down pointing arrow. The numbers are custom and can be adjusted to change the size of the arrow and its position.

```
.overviews-list > li.active > ul.submenu > li.active {
  position: relative;
}

.overviews-list > li.active > ul.submenu > li.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 15px solid white;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  top: 25%;
  right: 10px;
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/T2HuD/2/)

Comment: Thats awesome, how can i get it so the arrow is pointing right? And that the point is at the end of the li pointing to the content. Like the one here http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/paramount/eagleeye/

Comment: Play with the border color to see how the arrow changes. Basically which ever way you want the arrow to point, change the OPPOSITE side to white. So, pointing right, you want the LEFT border color to be white. Note that you may have to play with the position numbers to get it exactly where you want,

Answer (score 4):

I do this for something else but it should work for you too...

```
.pdfLink:before {
content:"\25BA";
color:#FF0000;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

}

All codes I have tried work. I can't recall how I came across that format for the char code, but the format is obvious if you check out this [char description](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25BA/index.htm).

Comment: So weird that this doesn't appear as it should on android in 2022... :(