# Design tooltip with arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: click on this link to see the tooltip I'm to design]

Hi I've problem with my tooltip the arrow doesn't show, also I don't how to place the arrow on front of the tooltip, I included a image of the tooltip I would like to design.I started to learn html5 and css3, can anyone help please.

```css
  a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width:140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 73px;
  line-height: 73px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
a.tooltips span::before {
  content:"\2190";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
 margin-left: -8px;
  /* width: 0; height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent; */
}
.span-content:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 7px;
}
.wrap-content{
position:relative
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.4;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.wrap-arrow{
  
widows:50px ;
height:50px ;
}
span.arrowup{
 background-image: url('arrowup.png') ;
}
```

```html
 <div style="margin-top:200px;margin-left:200px" >
    <a class="tooltips" href="#">bankcheck
        <span>Tooltipbankcheck</span></a>
        <span class="wrap-content span-content"></span></a>
        <span class="wrap-arrow arrowup"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use CSS triangles to create that arrow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010044/looking-to-use-pseudo-elements-to-create-a-triangle

Comment: How open are you to using a plugin/framework? Try Jquery-ui Tooltip: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the issue is about positioning. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 73px;
  line-height: 73px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a.tooltips span::before {
  content: "\21D3";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: red;
}

.span-content:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 7px;
}

.wrap-content {
  position: relative
}

a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.7;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.wrap-arrow {
  widows: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

span.arrowup {
  background-image: url('arrowup.png');
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:200px;margin-left:200px">
  <a class="tooltips" href="#">bankcheck
        <span>Tooltipbankcheck</span></a>
  <span class="wrap-content span-content"></span></a>
  <span class="wrap-arrow arrowup"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can I change the content to sprite png

Comment: RaJesh RiJo I tried to add the image but it doesn't work anymore

Comment: please create a new question or fiddler with working code. so that can look into it.

Comment: its fine how can I resize the content icon